# SkyScanner 415 Status Code when creating a session

Tags: node.js, http-post, skyscanner

I am trying to create a session on my Node JS application doing something like this:

```
import * as request from 'request';
const apiKey = '123123123123123123';
const urlApi = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0?apikey=' + apiKey;

const headers = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                };

var options = {
                url: urlApi,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                data: {
                    country: 'UK',
                    currency: 'GBP',
                    locale: 'en-GB',
                    locationSchema: 'iata',
                    apikey: '123123123123123123',
                    grouppricing: 'on',
                    originplace: 'EDI',
                    destinationplace: 'LHR',
                    outbounddate: '2016-12-29',
                    inbounddate: '2016-12-05',
                    adults: 1,
                    children: 0,
                    infants: 0,
                    cabinclass: 'Economy'
                }
};

request.post(options, function(error: Error, response: any, body: any)
{
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 415) {
        console.log('Error: ' + response.statusCode);
    }
    else {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
});
```

However, it always return statusCode 415. I am following the documentation from here https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us/articles/211308489-Flights-Live-Pricing but I haven't had any luck so far...

Comment: You have a typo in your URL. It should be  /v1.0/?apiKey=.....

Comment: I have exact the same problem. Were you able to find a solution for that problem? Would be great if you could update your post if so.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue actually you are using **body** in request params you should use form instead to append values as form instead of Stringified JSON or Serialized query params

```
var apiKey = "1234567897avasd85asd1a5dasd5a";
request.post("http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0?apiKey=" + apiKey, {
    form :{   // you were using body here use form instead
        country: 'UK',
        currency: 'GBP',
        locale: 'en-GB',
        locationSchema: 'iata',
        apikey: apiKey,
        grouppricing: 'on',
        originplace: 'EDI',
        destinationplace: 'LHR',
        outbounddate: '2018-08-09',
        inbounddate: '2018-08-29',
        adults: "1",
        children: "0",
        infants: "0",
        cabinclass: 'Economy'
    },
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
},function(error,response){
   if(!error){
    console.log(response.headers.location);
   }else{
    console.log("still got errors");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After I posted my question I have found the reason for my missed request. I used the queries in the url but you need to put them in the post body by replacing property data with body. I guess you also need to use json: true in the request options.

Consider https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback